# How to get magnitude and corresponding frequency after FFT

Tags: java, fft

How can I get the magnitudes and corresponding frequencies after performing FFT on a dataset. I need to plot the magnitude vs frequencies for a dataset. Also, why are we increasing the size of our FFT array as twice the size of actual dataset? Then the size of resulting output array is again different, Please help me understand this FFT code. Further, when is complexforward FFT and when realForward FFT is performed? Difference between the two? I need to perform FFT on a dataset and get the magnitude after FFT and corresponding frequencies for each magnitude.

```
                int length = data.length;
                FloatFFT_1D fftDo = new FloatFFT_1D(length);
                float[] fft = new float[length * 2];
                System.arraycopy(data, 0, fft, 0, length);
                fftDo.complexForward(fft);
                //for(double d: fft) {
                    //System.out.println(d);
                //}
                float outputfft[] = new float[(fft.length+1)/2];
                if(fft.length%2==0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < length/2; i++){
                        outputfft[i]= (float) Math.sqrt((Math.pow(fft[2*i],2))+(Math.pow(fft[(2*(i))+1], 2)));
                    }
                }else{
                    for(int i = 0; i < (length/2)+1; i++){
                        outputfft[i]= (float) Math.sqrt((Math.pow(fft[2*i],2))+(Math.pow(fft[(2*i)+1], 2)));
                    }
                }
                for (float f : outputfft) {
                    System.out.println(f);
                }
```

Comment: Please add stacktrace

Comment: length / 2 +1 != length +1 / 2 ... `float outputfft[] = new float[(data.length+1)/2];` vs `for(int i = 0; i < length/2+1; i++)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't really understand why array sizes are different. I have modified my question trying to make it more clear that what I actually want. I am new to Java and also to FFT. Please help me understand the code if you can.. I have just tried to copy it from various sources and tried to implement it on my dataset. But could not make it work even after making the change you suggested. Not sure how to add stacktrace..do you mean just print the output at every step?

Comment: OK, one step back ... A Stacktrace is the output you get when an exception happens. All that "BlahblahException at ... at ... at ..." Most of the time it leads you to the place where the actual bug is hiding.

Comment: Array sizes may differ because you have two ways to compute them: a) length / 2 +1 and (length+1)/2 they may be differently rounded. To avoid that error, you can simply use the array that you are using in the for-condition: `for(int i=0; i<outputfft.length;i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FFT of a real-valued data vector is by definition complex and symmetric. If you have a vector length of N samples you will get a FFT of N frequency data separated in frequency by Fs/N, where Fs is the sampling frequency. Your output vector is twice the size since the complex data is interleaved [re,im,re,im ...].
The output data is half the size since it is symmetric and you only need to view the first half corresponding to frequencies [0 .. Fs/2] the upper half is [-Fs/2 .. 0)

If you have an even-symmetric input data, X(-n)=X(n), or odd-symmetric, X(-n)=-X(n), you may use the realForward function

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So, in the code mentioned in my question, my data is of length say N and output vector which is fft[] is of length (2N), then the output data which is outputfft[] is of length (N+1).. not really half the size of data? Also, if you can tell me how to retrieve frequencies from the output of fft?, and the difference between realForward fft and complexForward fft?

Comment: In your code the outputfft is of length (N+1)/2 and I suppose it is to reserve space for odd length input data. The frequency vector starts at 0 and are spaced with Fs/N  [0  Fs/N 2Fs/N 3Fs/N ...]

Comment: @Aqua Actually, your output vector should have the same size as your intput vector. Just that it is complex numbers. So you have two possibilities: 1. Make input also "complex" by adding an Imaginary part that is 0 or 2. Make output twice as large to account for interleaving Real and Img parts.

Comment: Zeros could be because there is no data in that frequency. But as I said, number of "datapoints" must be the same. But apart from that: Please still add your stacktrace to the question.